# Build Vue3 with Vite to deploy into "subfolder" URL defined by Octopus variable substitution

Tags: vite, octopus-deploy

I need to host my Vue3 app not in the root of the domain but in a subfolder e.g. `https://my.domain.com/vue-app/`. I have found this in a vite documentation: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path and tried to add `base` into my `vite.config.js` like:

```js
    // vite.config.js
    export default defineConfig({
      base: "#{AppBaseUrl}",
      // ... the rest of config
    })
```

But it didn't helped. After the build `index.html` still contains links to `/assets/...` e.g.

```html
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-789e2ef4.js"></script>
```

next I tried to use command line parameter `--base="#{AppBaseUrl}"` with no luck.

The APP was created using `npm init vue@latest` and updated to latest versions of vite and vue3.

Am I missing something?